# maximum recursion depth exceeded: abstract property inheritance in python

Tags: python-3.x, abstract-class, abc

I am trying to define an abstract class with an abstract property that can then be inherited in a concrete class. But it is giving me `maximum recursion depth exceeded`.
`Vechile` is an abstract class and `Car` implements that class. The base class has a property called `parking_ticket` which I am keeping out of the `__init__` of the abstract class and defining a property called `parking_ticket` to act as a getter and setter. Please help me to point out where is the mistake.

Abstract Class

```
"""
module string
"""
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from vehicle_type import VehicleType
from parking_ticket import ParkingTicket


class Vechile(ABC):
    """
    class docstring
    """
    @abstractmethod
    def __init__(self, license_plate: str,
                 kind_of_vehicle: VehicleType) -> None:
        self.plate_number = license_plate
        self.vehicle_type = kind_of_vehicle
        self.parking_ticket = None

    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def parking_ticket(self):
        pass

    @parking_ticket.setter
    @abstractmethod
    def parking_ticket(self, parking_ticket: ParkingTicket):
        pass
```

Concrete Class

```
from vehicle import Vechile
from vehicle_type import VehicleType
from parking_ticket import ParkingTicket
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


class Car(Vechile):

    def __init__(self,
                 license_plate: str) -> None:
        super().__init__(license_plate, VehicleType.CAR)

    @property
    def parking_ticket(self):
        return self.parking_ticket

    @parking_ticket.setter
    def parking_ticket(self,
                       ticket: ParkingTicket):
        self.parking_ticket = ticket


p_ticket = ParkingTicket(ticket_number="123",
                         plate_number="12345",
                         allocated_spot_id=10,
                         issued_at=datetime.utcnow(),
                         vaccated_at=datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(hours=5),
                         charges=50
                         )
c = Car('MH53TS7618')
c.parking_ticket = p_ticket
print(c)
```

Comment: Typo in the class name, you wrote "Vechile".

Answer (score 0):

found the answer for it. I was using the same variable name as the method name and instance variable. hence the run time exception was occuring.